# React - Split an attribute to two

Tags: reactjs

I have this 2d array,

```
let records = [{firstname_lastname: 'aaa_bbb', age=11},{firstname_lastname:'ccc_ddd', age:22}]
```

I need to break firstname_lastname to two separate attributes:

```
[{firstname:'aaa', lastname:'bbb', age:11},{firstname:'ccc', lastname:'ddd', age:22}]
```

I did it using Map and Split

```
let recordsArr =  records.map((item)=>({
    'firstname':item['firstname_lastname'].split('_')[0],
    'lastname':item['firstname_lastname'].split('_')[1],
    'age':item['age']})
```

I was wondering if there is a better/faster way of doing it?

Comment: Not better or faster but you *could* do `let newItem = {age: item.age}; [newItem.firstname, newItem.lastname] = item.firstname_lastname.split('_'); return newItem;` to avoid calling `.split` twice. I guess one thing that can be objectively be improved is to use dot notation instead of bracket notation to access properties wherever possible.

Comment: You are doing it the right way. Map is for n -> n list transformations which is exactly what you're trying to achieve. As @FelixKling says, the bracket object access notation should be dot notation. If instead you want advice about adding resilence/error handling to this function, please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this question, I just echo @Felix-kling and @windowsill comments. I mapped Records to the function below:

```
    function splitName(record){
        let newRecord = {age: record.age};
        [newRecord.firstname, newRecord.lastname] = record. firstname_lastname.split('_');
        return newRecord}
```

To do a comparison, ran the initial solution (in the question) along with above function for ~1M records, turns out the performance would stay the same for both ways.